# How to optimize toggling className between different menu items by React?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, menu, header

I have header component, where I want to toggle className between all the elements of menu (if one of the elements of menu is active and user is clicking to another element - this element become active and all others no). I have a code like this

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './header.scss';

export const Header = ({ favoriteCount }) => {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
  function toggleClass(index) {
    setActiveIndex(index);
  }

  return (
    <header className="header">
      <div className="container header-container">
        <ul className="header-menu">
          <li>
            <a
              className={
                activeIndex === 0
                  ? 'header-menu__link active'
                  : 'header-menu__link'
              }
              onClick={() => {
                toggleClass(0);
              }}
              href="##"
            >
              Characters
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a
              className={
                activeIndex === 1
                  ? 'header-menu__link active'
                  : 'header-menu__link'
              }
              onClick={() => {
                toggleClass(0);
              }}
              href="##"
            >
              Favorites
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div className="header-favorite-count">
          <i className="far fa-heart"></i>
          {favoriteCount}
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
};
```

and styles to visualise toggling classes

```
  &-menu__link {
    color: lightgray;
  }

  .active {
    color: #fff;
  }
```

This approach is working but looks creepy. Maybe somebody knows how to optimize it?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the index, I'd use the text of the item. I'd also include that text in the `href` so that there's an indication of what the anchor leads to. To avoid repeated code, you might put the menu items in a reusable array, something like this:

```
const menuItems = [
    "Characters",
    "Favorites",
];

export const Header = ({ favoriteCount }) => {
    const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState("");

    const setActiveItem = useCallback((event) => {
        setActiveItem(event.currentTarget.href.substring(2));
    }, []);

    const list = menuItems.map(item =>
        <li key={item}>
            <a
                className={`header-menu__link ${item === activeItem ? "active" : ""}`}
                onClick={setActiveItem}
                href={"##" + item}>
                {item}
            </a>
        </li>
    );
  
    return (
        <header className="header">
            <div className="container header-container">
                <ul className="header-menu">
                    {list}}
                </ul>
                <div className="header-favorite-count">
                    <i className="far fa-heart"></i>
                    {favoriteCount}
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    );
};
```